# oracle apex installation 5.1.4?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle12c

[image: Command prompt of oracle apex installation]

I don't know why I am running into this problem can anybody help me sort it out I followed mentioned steps at oracle apex installation guide but cannot get it installed I am using oracle 12c SE. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you should first download & install database patch #20618595. Have a look [here](http://jastraub.blogspot.hr/2015/04/upgrading-to-application-express-50-in.html) for more info.